# AngularJS views not displaying in Firefox

Tags: angularjs

We have an app that works fine in Edge and Chrome, but Firefox will not display the HTML generated by AngularJS. The app is using ui-router and components. Inspecting the page using the Developer Tools, you can clearly see the HTML, but it is greyed out and not visible on the page. What's going on?

[image]

Comment: any errors in browser console?

Comment: Appears your app is inside a `<base>` but  base element doesn't allow content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: @charlietfl this is the answer. I didn't realize `<base>` was a reserved HTML element.

Comment: Ahhh..so you made a custom directive for `<base>` then also?

Comment: Kind-of, it's actually a Component https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component